# What is proper way to specify relative path to file in M3U playlists?

Tags: audio, mp3, media-player, playlist

What is proper way to specify the path to mp3 file in M3U playlists, for use playlists in hardware players, like Compact & Shelf Stereos, Micro Component Systems, Car Audio Players?
I understand the path should be relative, for more reliable playback. For example, Windows Media Player m3u playlist have two dots before the leading back slash:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:0,Artist - Track Name (Mix).mp3
..\My Album\Artist - Track Name (Mix).mp3
```

Does this dots and leading back slashes make any sense for hardware players?

Comment: My paths looked like "file:///path/to/my/file" and didn't think I could remove "file://". (I read too fast and it might help others)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the players I've seen (Windows Media Player included) accept relative paths.

The `..` means one directory up.  If you wanted to specify the current path, either use `.`, or don't specify it at all.

If you have compatibility problems, consider using regular "forward" slashes `/` instead.  Most hardware players aren't running Windows, and most Windows software can handle the regular slashes even though Windows paths use backslashes `\`.

Comment: So if "My Folder" is in DVD root directory, I should use path `"My Folder/Artist - Track Name (Mix).mp3"`?

Comment: There is no need for leading slash in path?

Comment: @vestix5 No, you don't want a leading slash.  That would mean go to the root of the file system.

Comment: One note: is ir possible to adjust Windows Media Player settings to make it exclude dots and leading slash from path?

Comment: You don't need to. It reads paths the same as anything else.

Comment: I mean to use playlists on hardware players, not on WMP. I used WMP just to create m3u.

Comment: Windows Media Player converts paths of wpl and m3u files to absolute paths eventually. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @bytecode77 I'm not sure what you mean.  Post an example on SuperUser.com.

Comment: I actually posted one a couple of days ago: http://superuser.com/questions/1094042/windows-media-player-playlist-wlp-how-to-save-relative-paths/1096249 - WMP eventually changed the relative paths to absolute ones within a matter of hours. I have no idea why WMP rebuilds all playlists, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-line command to convert absolute to relative for an .m3u file **(update playlistname and username before using)**:

```
name='playlistname'; cd /Volumes/'Mac Storage'/Music/Music/playlists; cat $name.m3u >> $name-old.m3u; LC_ALL=C sed -i '' 's/\\Users\\username\\Music\\/\.\.\//g' $name.m3u
```

What it means:

- `name='playlistname'` - The name of the playlist.m3u file you wish to change.
- `cd ~/Music/playlists;` - Navigates to the playlists folder.
- `cat playlist.m3u >> playlist-old.m3u;` - Backs up your playlist before making changes.
- `sed -i '' 's/oldtext/newtext/g' playlist.m3u` - In the target playlist, replaces all instances (`g` for global) of the oldtext (the absolute path) with newtext (the relative path: `../`).
- `LC_ALL=C` avoids an error that sometimes comes up: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`.